# in Selenium webdriver 2 testng, difficult to fetch the hardcoded elements in application?

Tags: selenium, testng

In selenium Webdriver testng, i have hardcoded some elements in my program but the testng is not finding the element.so i gave thread.sleep but in case its working and in other case not working.i gave explicit function also.TO find Element , i written the method called findelement

```
    public  findElement(String Locator)
{
    locator(Locator);
    identifyBy (identifier);


}

public static void locator(String locator) {

    }
```

This is what i done in my selenium framework.please help me to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public static void waitForElementToAppear(WebDriver driver, By selector, long timeOutInSeconds) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(selector));
  }
```

Comment: my object locator is in string , how i can convert into By?then it will be a big problem in my Framework

Comment: change it to string or selector (selector is better )

Comment: if i change into string, it throws error in visibilityOfElementLocated